# PHP Stapler and Imagine Image autororate issue

Tags: php, image, exif, php-imagine

I'm getting some inconsistency with the autorotate functionality of Stapler, and was hoping someone could explain what's happening.

My styles are defined as follows on an Eloquent model:

```
'styles' => [
    'thumbnail' => [
        'dimensions' => '300',
        'auto_orient' => true,
        'convert_options' => ['quality' => 100],
    ],
    'standard' => [
        'dimensions' => 'x275',
        'auto_orient' => true,
        'convert_options' => ['quality' => 100],
    ],
    'zoom' => function($file, $imagine) {
        $image = $imagine
            ->setMetadataReader(new \Imagine\Image\Metadata\ExifMetadataReader)
            ->open($file->getRealPath());

        // Auto rotate the image
        $filter = new \Imagine\Filter\Basic\Autorotate;
        $filter->apply($image);

        // Get the current size
        $size = $image->getSize();

        // Scale down to zoom size only if
        // image is wide enough.
        if ($size->getWidth() > 1280) {
            $newSize = $size->widen(1280);
            $image->resize($newSize);
        }

        return $image;
    }
]
```

The issue is that, for a particular image, the `zoom` style is not working correctly. It's rotating the image 90 degrees, even though the original is already upright.

Here's a screenshot of the original image, you can see it's upright:

[image]

Here's a screenshot of the image after being processed by the `zoom` style. It's rotated 90 degrees:

[image]

As you can see, I also have `autorotate` set to true for the `thumbnail` and `standard` styles, but those images are not being rotated 90 degrees and appear correctly after processing.

The strange thing is that when I check the exif orientation data for the original image, it has a value of 6, which means the image should be rotated 90 degrees. If that's the case, why do the other styles not get rotated also?

```
$imagine = new Imagine\Imagick\Imagine;
$image = $imagine->open('https://s3.amazonaws.com/path/to/original/image.jpg');
echo $image->metadata()->toArray()['ifd0.Orientation'];

// Output is 6
```

So I am wondering why the exif orientation is 6 if this image is already upright. Also, why is the image only getting rotated for the `zoom` style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I needed to `return $image->strip()` in order to remove the exif data after auto rotating the image.